# How to get previous record and next record values in ruby on rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have two requirements in my project.

1) I have to add a condition in database query where the current update time of a particular ID should be less than the next ID creation time.

2) Here I have to get a record of previous ID and compare with current ID record.

I am struggling on these two issues for last few days. If some one can throw some light on this then it will be of great help.

Thanks

**Update:** I am using Rails 2 here.

Answer (score 0):

For your question 2:

Not tested - written on an iPhone :-)

```
select my_table.id, previous.id
from my_table
 , my_table previous
where previous.id < my_table.id
  and not exists (
    select 1 from my_table ex
    where ex.id > previous.id
      and ex.id < my_table.id
    )
```

Answer to Q 1 seems similar as far as I understand. Same for getting the next id amd a condition comparing the timestamps.